# ClosedXML. Adding DataTable to existing Excel worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

How using [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) library in fastest way (from performance point of view) add values from `DataTable` to already existing Excel worksheet?

NOTE: There is way to create new worksheet with `DataTable` parameter, but the main issue is in adding values to existing worksheet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're dealing with millions of cells and you want to insert the data as fast as possible while consuming the minimum amount of memory then [SAX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2010/06/22/writing-large-excel-files-with-the-open-xml-sdk.aspx) is the way to go.

If you want ClosedXML to do the work for you then use:

```
cell.Value = dataTable;
or
cell.SetValue(dataTable);
or
cell.InsertData(dataTable);
or
cell.InsertTable(dataTable);
```

See the "Inserting Data/Tables" section of the [Documentation](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/documentation)

Comment: Documentation moved to GitHub: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Adding-DataTable-as-Worksheet